# How can I make my Firestore search repeatable?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

**Background**

I have search functionality on the website that uses 'array-contains' to show the user all of the products that match the search query. This works by having an input in the 'nav' component that passes the search through queryparams to the results component.

***Nav:***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { User } from 'src/app/user/email-login/user.model';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shell',
  templateUrl: './shell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shell.component.scss']
})
export class ShellComponent {

  user$: Observable<User>;
  searchResult;
  userID: string;

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset])
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log('I just logged someone in!')
          return this.db.doc<User>('users/${user.uid}').valueChanges();
        }
        else{
          return of (null);
        }
      })
    )
  }

  search(event: any){
    var searchQuery;
    searchQuery = event.target.value;
    console.log('routing');
    let userSearch: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        searchValue: searchQuery
      }
    }
    this.router.navigate(['search-results'], userSearch);
  }
}
```

***Search Result:***

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, SimpleChanges, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-results',
  templateUrl: './search-results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-results.component.scss']
})
export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  searchQuery: string;
  searchResults;
  collectionRef;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    console.log('being loaded..');
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(search =>{
      this.searchQuery = search.searchValue;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchResults = this.db.collection('products', ref => ref.where('keywords', 'array-contains', this.searchQuery)).valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){ // You need to update here the searchQuery
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(search =>{
      this.searchQuery = search.searchValue;
      this.searchResults = this.db.collection('products', ref => 
    ref.where('keywords', 'array-contains', this.searchQuery)).valueChanges();
  });

  console.log(changes);
}

}
```

**The Problem**

The search works as expected when performed from a page other than the search results page, however, in the event that a user does a search, gets routed to the results page, and does another search, the results don't get update as the 'search results' do not get triggered again (despite the search function in nav being triggered'.

How can I modify my solution to allow users to do another search after the first? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I'm not sure what.

Working example: https://padder-939bc.firebaseapp.com/

Available search criteria for testing: 'black', 'blue', 'white'

Comment: Do you want to update the search results? I am not understanding correctly what are you trying to say,  to search for results you click a button or you want the page updating meanwhile you are typing for a search?

Comment: Hi @NibrassH - the search is initiated when the user pressed 'enter' after typing their search, doing so triggers the 'search' function in the above question.

Comment: @NibrassH I've updated the question with a link to the website - 'blue', 'black' and 'white are all keywords that can be searched. If I search 'blue' it shows me the results, however, if I then stay on the results page and type 'black' into my search, the results do not change despite the search function being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to update data for the search result because you are initializing the searchQuery in the constructor which is called once.

You have to update the searchQuery in a function of Angular called [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) like following:

Search Results:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private db: AngularFirestore) {
    console.log('being loaded..');
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(search =>{
        this.searchQuery = search.searchValue;
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.searchResults = this.db.collection('products', ref => 
      ref.where('keywords', 'array-contains', this.searchQuery)).valueChanges();
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){ // You need to update here the searchQuery

      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(search =>{
        this.searchQuery = search.searchValue;
        this.searchResults = this.db.collection('products', ref => 
      ref.where('keywords', 'array-contains', this.searchQuery)).valueChanges();
    });
 }
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Could you please console.log(changes) inside the function ngOnChanges , and share the output please?

Comment: it doesn't seem like ngOnChanges is being triggered. I've added the console.log but nothing is getting output

Comment: Please import the library as following: 

import { onChanges } from '@angular/core'.
And add onChanges interface to your class : " Class Myclass implements OnChanges "

Comment: hmm, I've done this - it seems that the 'search results' page isn't getting re-loaded, so I'm not sure whether this is an issue with my routing?

Comment: The 'Nav' referenced above is the navigation bar component on the website linked. It is present at all times across the website. 'Search Result' is the component of the page that gets loaded after a search and is effectively loaded underneath the navbar. The only other code (in addition to the above), is HTML

Comment: Could you please share the complete classes otherwise I am not able to reproduce your issue. The function search, ngOnInit and the constructor are inside a class so I would like to have a look on the entire code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209839/discussion-between-peterl1995-and-nibrass-h).

Comment: I send a message in the chat, but I am putting here it as well. Could you please remove the OnInit method from the SearchResultsComponent class and also remove the implements Oninit interface ?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I have tried removing both and the result is that no results are returned on either the initial search or any further searches